# Android - How should i localize strings in non-UI classes?

Tags: android, localization

I have a few classes that, although manipulate strings to later show to the user, are not directly connected to the UI and i would like to keep them in their own self-contained package/library (because they constitute a logical model that i consider reusing in future apps).

Whether i put them in a separate library or not i believe my question remains the same.

I would like to implement proper localization for the strings that these classes manipulate, but i guess it's not good practice to use the application context in classes that aren't directly connected to the UI because it makes them dependent on the app.

What pattern should i follow?

Comment: "i guess it's not good practice to use the application context in classes that aren't directly connected to the UI because it makes them dependent on the app" -- I do not understand your concern here. Plenty of libraries use the application context.

Comment: So is it advisable for a library to get a string using the context and an identifier like R.string.something that is defined in the app's res/values/strings.xml? What happens if the app doesn't define that identifier?

Comment: Presumably your library would have its own strings in its own string resources. The app can override those if needed.

Comment: What if it's not a library but rather just a package inside the app? I have been told that, in Android, one should only localize strings that are in UI classes such as Activities and Fragments. Did i misunderstand this principle?

Comment: I have no idea who told you that. Ideally, you localize any string that the user sees.

Comment: Ok i think my confusion was that i was thinking of a Java library (JAR) instead of an Android library (AAR). In the first i couldn't have my own resource strings but in the second i can. Also i guess i was misinformed about the "localize only UI" principle. Thanks!

Comment: "In the first i couldn't have my own resource strings but in the second i can" -- correct. Unless you are creating a library that will be used by non-Android Java projects, there is little value in creating a JAR instead of an AAR.